# Is there anything i am doing wrong while mapping or while using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

In src folder, I have the following components,

1. addNotes.js

```
import noteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext';
 
const AddNote = () => {
    const context = useContext(noteContext);
 
    const [note, setNote] = useState({title:" ",description:" ",tag:"default "})
    const { addNote } = context;
 
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addNote(note.title, note.description,note.tag);
    }
 
    const onChange = (e) => {
        setNote({...note,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }
    return (
        <div> <div className="container my-3">
            <h2>ADD A NOTE</h2>
 
            {/* FORM */}
            <form className='my-3'>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="title" name='title' onChange={onChange} aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="description" className="form-label">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="description" name='description' onChange={onChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3 form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>ADD NOTE</button>
            </form>
 
        </div></div>
    )
}
 
export default AddNote
```

2. Home.js

```
import Notes from './Notes'
 
 
export default function Home() {
 
  return (
    <div >
     
<Notes/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

3. Navbar.js

```
import { NavLink ,useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
 
 
export default function Navbar() {
    let location = useLocation();
    useEffect(()=>{
        // console.log(location.pathname);
    },[location])
   
    return (
        <>
 
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light py-3 shadow-sm">
                <div className="container">
                    <NavLink className="navbar-brand fw-bold f-4 fs-2" to="/">iNotebook</NavLink>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 fs-4">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className={`nav-link  ${location.pathname === "/"?"active":" "}` }aria-current="page" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className={`nav-link  ${location.pathname === "/about"?"active":" "}` }to="/about">About</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form className="d-flex" role="search">
                            <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                            <button className="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}
```

4. NoteItem.js

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import noteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext';
 
 
const NoteItem = (props) => {
 
    const context = useContext(noteContext);
    const {deleteNote} =context;
    const  {note}  = props;
 
    // console.log(note.tittle);
    return (
        <div className='col-md-3  '>
            <div className="card my-3">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{note.tittle}</h5>
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-trash-can mx-2" onClick={()=>{deleteNote(note._id)}}></i>
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square mx-2"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p className="card-text">{note.description} </p>
                   
 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
 
export default NoteItem
```

5. Notes.js

```
import noteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext';
import AddNote from './AddNote';
import NoteItem from './NoteItem';
const Notes = () => {
  const context = useContext(noteContext);
  const { notes, getNotes } = context;
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes()
 
  }, [])
  console.log(notes);
 
 
   if(notes.length>0){
  return (<>
 
    <AddNote />
    <div className=" row my-3 mx-3">;
      <h3>YOUR NOTE</h3>
      {notes.map((note,index) => {
        return <NoteItem key={index} note={note} />
      })}
    </div>
  </>
  )}else{
return (
    <div>Loading....</div>
)
   }
}
 
 
export default Notes;
```

Then in src, I have folder named context in context and I have another folder which is notes. There are two more files,

1. noteContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
 
const noteContext = createContext();
 
export default noteContext;
```

2. NoteState.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import NoteContext from "./noteContext";
 
const NoteState = (props) => {
  const host = "http://localhost:5000"
  const notesInitial = [];
 
 
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(notesInitial)
 
 
 
  //  FETCH A NOTE
  const getNotes = async () => {
 
    // API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/fetchallnotes`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjJiNDRmMjIzNWVhZmNkM2FhODRmMTg1In0sImlhdCI6MTY1NTk4NzgyNH0.LRueOf_bDWJB6NJ5jmN-ZQxStPPUt0ppW2G0s5VcRr4"
      }
    });
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json);
    setNotes(json);
 
  }
 
 
 
  //  ADD A NOTE
  const addNote = async (title, description, tag) => {
 
    // API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/addnote`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjJiNDRmMjIzNWVhZmNkM2FhODRmMTg1In0sImlhdCI6MTY1NTk4NzgyNH0.LRueOf_bDWJB6NJ5jmN-ZQxStPPUt0ppW2G0s5VcRr4"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title, description, tag })
    });
 
    console.log("Adding a new note");
    const note = {
      "_id": "62b45b1eff7f",
      "user": "62b44f2235eafcd3aa84f185",
      "title": title,
      "description": description,
      "tag": tag,
      "date": "2022-06-24T10:55:43.455Z",
      "__v": 0
    };
    setNotes(notes.concat(note))
  }
 
  // DELETE A NOTE
 
  // TODO API CALL
 
  const deleteNote = (id) => {
    console.log("This is deleting node" + id);
    const newNotes = notes.filter((note) => { return note._id !== id })
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }
 
  // EDIT A NOTE
 
  const editNote = async (id, title, description, tag) => {
    // API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/updatenote/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjJiNDRmMjIzNWVhZmNkM2FhODRmMTg1In0sImlhdCI6MTY1NTk4NzgyNH0.LRueOf_bDWJB6NJ5jmN-ZQxStPPUt0ppW2G0s5VcRr4"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title, description, tag })
    });
    // const json = response.json()
    // LOGIC TO EDIT IN CLIENT
    for (let index = 0; index < notes.length; index++) {
      const element = notes[index];
      if (element._id === id) {
        element.title = title;
        element.description = description;
        element.tag = tag;
      }
    }
  }
 
  return (
    <NoteContext.Provider value={{ notes, addNote, deleteNote, editNote, getNotes }}>
      {props.children}
    </NoteContext.Provider>
  )
}
 
// console.log(notes);
 
export default NoteState;
```

And my App.js looks like below,

```
import './App.css';
 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
 
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import NoteState from './context/notes/NoteState';
import Alert from './components/Alert';
 
function App() {
  return (
    <>
 
      <NoteState>
        <Router>
          <Navbar />
          {/* <Alert message="this is amazing react course"/> */}
          <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" exact element={<About />} />
          </Routes>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </NoteState>
 
 
    </>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

Here are two more files which I have not included which is alert.js and About.js as they are of no use.

This is the whole code of all the components that are there with the context API code.
The main problem occurring in noteItem.js is I am getting an array of notes with id and title in the console but when  I use it in a component as `{note.title}` or `{note.description}`. It is showing undefined.

Comment: Is this possibly the same/similar React key issue as your other question [here](/questions/72801319/warning-like-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop)? Are you sure the `notes` state is correctly updated to the value you expect? Can you edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive code example? [mcve] It may be helpful to also try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live. Please mock the notes fetch request with a valid response value if you do.

Comment: I am not getting your point sir can you tell me which file i should share with you to get the proper answer @DrewReese

Comment: I don't know about any specific files, but I was just asking for complete component code snippets. For example, what is calling `getNotes`, and where and when is it called? What is rendering the second snippet with `NoteContext.Provider`? Where is the `Notes` component rendered? Is `console.log(notes);` the log image with the array of length 2? What is the result of `console.log(note);` in the `NoteItem` component? I was also asking if you could create a running codesandbox demo that we could inspect live, to see what's updated and where/how.

Comment: Sir i am unable to create sand box but here is the google docs where i  have created all the files please do check them [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j0OU2C41rhIgVABk9n-Rlp9X2kMv_ZRIPTxxIOK7Ve4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @DrewReese please do check it out it will be very helpful

Comment: Can you just include that code in your post here then? All relevant code should be included and self-contained in a SO post.

Comment: @DrewReese Sir, i had posted all of the code in the post please do check it

Comment: There's a typo, `note.tittle` should be `note.title`, otherwise I'm not able to reproduce the issue you describe. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/is-there-anything-i-am-doing-wrong-while-mapping-or-while-using-props-99weow).

Comment: @DrewReese sir, i can now add a note in my database but the thing is I can not fetch data from database in NoteItem when i do `console.log(note)` it is giving array of my fetched data but when i am using that data in component as `{note.title}` it is showing undefined

Comment: The `NoteItem` component doesn't appear to be fetching any data from any endpoint. `NoteItem` is passed a `note` prop from `Notes` where `notes` is the `notes` array state from the provider. If ***that*** `notes` state is updated correctly I see no reason for any of the data properties to be undefined in `NoteItem`. Seems the issue you are asking about now is either in ***making*** the DB request *or* ***processing*** the DB response. I don't have access to your DB and you haven't provided an example response value so it's difficult to say why you aren't able to update from the DB correctly.

Comment: The sandbox I created is effectively skipping the GET and POST network requests and using the mock result value you provided. Is that mock object not an accurate representation of the real data? You are updating data in a backend somewhere ***and*** also maintaining local `notes` state.... and then occasionally refetch the notes... which do you want to be the source of truth? Is the issue that fetching the notes wipes the local state and now the data is different (*for some reason*)? This is why we asked for the `getNotes` result value previously.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Notes = () => {
  const context = useContext(noteContext);
  const { notes, getNotes } = context; 
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes()
  
  }, [])
   if(notes.length>0){
  return (<>

    <AddNote />
    <div className=" row my-3 mx-3">;
      <h3>YOUR NOTE</h3>
      {notes.map((note,index) => {
        return <NoteItem key={index} note={note} />
      })}
    </div>
  </>
  )}else{
return (
    <div>Loading....</div>
)
   }
}


export default Notes;
```

Comment: still it is not working it is not updating data

Comment: The heading is there the component is there the icons are there but the value which i am passing are not updating

Comment: while i am doing console.log(note.tittle) it is showing undefined